Nodriver: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'closed'
I am learning nodriver (version 0.37) library https://ultrafunkamsterdam.github.io/nodriver/nodriver/quickstart.html
My actions
python3.11 -m venv venv
source venv/bin/activate
pip install nodriver


I am trying this code
import nodriver as uc

async def main():

    browser = await uc.start()
    page = await browser.get('https://www.nowsecure.nl')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    uc.loop().run_until_complete(main())

Error
python main.py      
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mascai/root_folder/dev/projects/54_nodriver/main.py", line 11, in <module>
    uc.loop().run_until_complete(main())
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.9_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/asyncio/base_events.py", line 654, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/mascai/root_folder/dev/projects/54_nodriver/main.py", line 5, in main
    browser = await uc.start()
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/mascai/root_folder/dev/projects/54_nodriver/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/nodriver/core/util.py", line 96, in start
    return await Browser.create(config)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/mascai/root_folder/dev/projects/54_nodriver/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/nodriver/core/browser.py", line 91, in create
    await instance.start()
  File "/Users/mascai/root_folder/dev/projects/54_nodriver/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/nodriver/core/browser.py", line 394, in start
    await self.connection.send(cdp.target.set_discover_targets(discover=True))
  File "/Users/mascai/root_folder/dev/projects/54_nodriver/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/nodriver/core/connection.py", line 412, in send
    if not self.websocket or self.closed:
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/mascai/root_folder/dev/projects/54_nodriver/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/nodriver/core/connection.py", line 368, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self.target, item)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'closed'
successfully removed temp profile /var/folders/t6/7jk0v3817zb2_xfb6bf0vxpc0000gn/T/uc_tedc5epz


When you get errors internal to a library like this, it's usually either a bug in the library or it's an incompatible version.

I suppose that I have to do some additional actions (e.g. install some special browser)

What worked for me was bumping websockets down to websockets==13.1 from 14.0 for nodriver==0.37

This worked for me... nodriver is a frustrating library in general.
